# AdSense in Sidebar of WordPress Zilah Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, adsense

Hi I have a WordPress site https:www.wpressmag.com with the Zillah Theme. In the theme there is no way to put a regular Sidebar, so I can not put AdSense ads in the Sidebar. Has anyone experience with this theme and cann tell me the clue?

Comment: It seems that sidebar is not expected by design in this theme. You may use adwords blocks inside the body.

Comment: Ok Thanks, I already tried this in the single.php but I only get to manage the ads getting placed on top of the page, so before the body... I guess it is not possible without adding new css classes.